# Best way to do a delete operation with GraphQL + graphene

Tags: graphql, graphene-python

I'm struggling to get my Delete operation working.
My Create, Read and Update are working fine, but a Delete has nothing to return.

```
class DeleteEmployeeInput(graphene.InputObjectType):
    """Arguments to delete an employee."""
    id = graphene.ID(required=True, description="Global Id of the employee.")


class DeleteEmployee(graphene.Mutation):
    """Delete an employee."""
    employee = graphene.Field(
        lambda: Employee, description="Employee deleted by this mutation.")

    class Arguments:
        input = DeleteEmployeeInput(required=True)

    def mutate(self, info, input):
        data = utils.input_to_dictionary(input)
        #data['edited'] = datetime.utcnow()

        employee = db_session.query(
            EmployeeModel).filter_by(id=data['id'])
        employee.delete(data['id'])
        db_session.commit()
        #employee = db_session.query(
            #EmployeeModel).filter_by(id=data['id']).first()

        #return DeleteEmployee(employee=employee)
```

What is the best way to delete an entry?
I assume I have to return an OK or an Error.

When I run my mutation:

```
mutation {
  deleteEmployee (input: {
       id: "RW1wbG95ZWU6MQ=="
  }) 
}
```

I get the error `Field \"deleteEmployee\" of type \"DeleteEmployee\" must have a sub selection."`

Note the commented out lines

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try replacing `employee = graphene.Field...` with `ok = graphene.Boolean()` and then make the last line of your mutate method `return DeleteEmployee(ok=True)`

Your mutate method will then look something like:

```
    def mutate(self, info, input):
        ... skipping deletion code ...
        db_session.commit()
        return DeleteEmployee(ok=True)
```

Comment: That worked perfectly. I'm relatively new to python as you may have noticed. What exactly happens in the return line `return DeleteEmployee(ok=True)`? It returns an new instance of the same class DeleteEmployee? The ok=True is an kwarg that is passed to the constructor of the graphene.Mutation class?

Comment: The last line of the mutate method creates an object that is the output of the mutation.  It would make more sense in the documentation if the `mutate` method was consistently shown a classmethod.

Comment: I'm still a bit confused, but I guess I have to grab some 101 udemy courses. For example the line `input = DeleteEmployeeInput(required=True)` The class `DeleteEmployeeInput` itself doesn't have a (visible) variable `required`. It is placed in the super() class `graphene.InputObjectType`?

Comment: `DeleteEmployeeInput` is defining the shape of the inputs, whereas inside `class Arguments` you are defining the relationship between `DeleteEmployee` and its inputs, which is why `required` goes there.

Comment: So `required` is a python convention and not a graphene variable? Because I don't see where the variable `required` is created

Comment: `required` is an argument to method that is creating the graphene field

Comment: `DeleteEmployeeInput` is an instance of `graphene.InputObjectType` with an additional attribute `id` right? So to my understanding the class attribute `required` has to be created inside `graphene.InputObjectType` but I don't see one in there. I'm coming from PHP btw, maybe I'm missing something crucial here.